# How to add up values in an array if they need to meet numerous criteria

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I am building a rudimentary budgeting tool on Google Sheets, where I intent to use a google form to enter new data([Data input sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIeHt.png)). After this I want to sum all expenses up, which timestamps are within the same year and month and have a common category like Technik or Nebenkosten(utility). This sum is supposed to go into a separate spreadsheet. [SummaryOfExpenses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLvCR.png) How can this be made possible

Comment: Share a sample workbook. Also show your desired output. `QUERY()` function may give you desired result. `SUMIFS()` will also can server the purpose.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you build a pivot table and group the dates by year and monthes.

[image]

You can do it into a separate spreadsheet of course.

Comment: How it could an answer?

Comment: "Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible"